# Load URL(button) in WebView with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

My program works to click a button itself with the following code in a web page:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            ourBrow.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('G03').click()"); 
        }
});
```

But when I try to run it again in another web page, I realized there is no such `document.getElementById('id')` in the Javascript. Here is the Javascript:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td width="18%" class="tableHeading">Career</td>
     <td class="tableHeading">Program</td>
     <td width="20%" class="tableHeading">Campus</td>
     <td width="25%" class="tableHeading">Term</td>
     <td width="15%" class="tableHeading">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowSpacer">
     <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowLowlight">
     <td class="data">Undergraduate</td>
     <td class="data">3642 - Photo; </td>
     <td class="data">KENS -Kens Campus</td>
     <td class="data">2012</td>
     <td class="data" align="right">
        <input class="button" type="submit" title="Update Enrolment" name="bsdsSubmit-0" value="Update Enrolment">
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="rowSpacer" colspan="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="rowHighlight"><td
```

I only copied the Javascript of the button, it was too huge to paste all them here. In this code, I only know: `class="button" type="submit" title="Update Enrolment" name="bsdsSubmit-0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use something like this,

```
<input type="button" value="Update Enrolment" onclick="location.href='required url'" />
```